# React - setState pass data to updater name

Tags: function, reactjs, state

There's a way to pass the name of the updater in setState?

[image]

i want to update a state by i dont want to create a function for each data.value that recives

so this code:

```
methodSelected = (event, data) => {
    data.checked
        ? this.setState(() => {
              return { data.value: true };
            })
        : this.setState(() => {
              return { data.value: false };
            });
};
```

could be something like this:

```
methodSelected = (event, data) => {
    data.checked
        ? this.setState(() => {
              return { email: true };     <<<<<< email it's data.value
            })
        : this.setState(() => {
              return { email: false };   <<<<<< email it's data.value
            });
};
```

it's possible with setState or there's another function with react that i can do that?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer and ctrl+f for "computed property"

Comment: `return { data.value: false };` is actually compilation error. Can you explain better what do you want?

Comment: @Misiur Post it like a answer to rate it and mark solved. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand right, you want to pass key to the object as a variable:

```
methodSelected = (event, data) => {
    data.checked
        ? this.setState({[data.value] : true})
        : this.setState({{[data.value] : false}});
};
```

or

```
methodSelected = (event, data) => {       
    this.setState({[data.value] : data.checked})
};
```